# Getting trouble in writing query laravel

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, mapping, eloquent-relationship

```
Can anyone help me to get the data . 
$ticketList = Ticket::with('appliance', 'brand')->get();
$userAppliances = DB::table('user_appliances')
            ->where('user_id', 5)
            ->pluck('appliance_id')
            ->toArray();

$userBrands = DB::table('user_brands')
            ->where('user_id', 5)
            ->pluck('brand_id')
            ->toArray();

$ticketList = $ticketList->map(function ($ticket) use ($userAppliances) {
                return $ticket->where($ticket->appliance_id,'=', $userAppliances);
            });
            dd($ticketList);
```

It returnd the collection. I want all the tickets, where ticket->brand_id and tickt->appliance_id includes {all the id i am getting in array from userBrands and userAppliances}. I am getting trouble in writing query

Comment: Instead of using map function use leftJoin and make one query and in that make all your conditions with where causes, definitely you will get the required data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out this

```
$userBrands = DB::table ('user_brands')
->where('user_id', 5)
->pluck('appliance_id')
->toArray();

$ticketList = Ticket::with('appliance', 'brand')
   ->where(function($query) use ($userBrands){
     
     $query->whereIn('appliance_id', $userBrands);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you neel That worked. I Got two more questions.  What if i have to : fetch the data   where userBrand doesnt exists in ticket.brand_id?? And Also, sometimes ticket.brand_id might ot be there in the table, in that case it throws an error right? How should I handle if ticket.brand_id exists only then `$query->whereIn('appliance_id', $userBrands) else ignore this line? @neel